# Find the Maclaurin series for $f(x) = (1+ x)^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Find the interval of convergence. (Please use Maclaurin Series)

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have found the terms $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$ basically the terms for the series. I can't get the general term $a_n$ to use for the ratio test.

Comment: Do you know about the Binomial Series?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility to find it, notice that $f(x)-3(1+x)f'(x)=0$.

Now from $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, find the induction relation $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{(\frac 13-n)}{n+1}a_n$ by formally derivating the series, re-indexing and identifying the coefficient of $x^n$ with zero.

Find back the "known" binomial coefficients $a_n=\dfrac {\frac 13(\frac 13-1)(\frac 13-2)\cdots(\frac 13-n+1)}{n!}$

For the ratio test, well, you have it already from the induction relation...

[Look at the compendium](http://www.h-k.fr/publications/data/adc.ps__annexes.maths.pdf) for all common expansions.